# Download Gmail Mail Content using R

Tags: r, email, message

I am trying to download gmails from my gmail account.  Most importantly I am interested in downloading the actual content of the mail along with other parameters receipt time, subject, to and from address.  I have tried using gmailr and edeR packages.  While gmailr helps in sending mails (which I have tried successfully, edeR helps in downloading only the topline data and not the message body.  I am seeking this data to test an classification model.  Is there a way to do it in R...I am not familiar with any other language.

Comment: Are you open to a solution where you would manually download your mail archive from Gmail ?

Comment: Steven Beaupre, i have around 4500 mails to download...but still would like to explore your solution to see if it helps

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could manually [retrieve an archive](https://www.google.com/settings/takeout) of your gmail and use `convert_mbox_eml()` from the `tm.plugin.mail` package to convert your `.mbox` (several mails in a single box) into an `eml` format (every mail in a single file) and then load it in a `VCorpus` using `readMail`:

```
library(tm)
library(tm.plugin.mail)

mail <- paste0(getwd(), "/mail")
convert_mbox_eml("yourarchive.mbox", mail)
vc <- VCorpus(DirSource(mail), readerControl = list(reader = readMail))
```